# Is it fine `quiting answering questions`?

Tags: discussion

I just found out a post that contains an answer and the answerer comments

> Either you provide us with a screenshot/photo of the "MINUS SIGN" you're talking about, or I'm done helping you.

I do get that this is a rude comment and spills out the reputation of the site as a whole.

We have just entered public beta so shouldn't we be a little more of Helping nature to newer users?

The post is here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/556/creating-partitions-for-the-elementary-os-installation

*Note: I have flagged the comment.*

Comment: Who was this user. The post is deleted now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that question was removed.

Yeah that's definitely not okay behavior. Understandably, helping less experienced users can be difficult, but we need to remain respectful. If you encounter users who are being abusive, definitely flag the post and feel free to link them to the [elementary Code of Conduct](https://elementary.io/code-of-conduct).

Comment: the ["Be Nice"](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) page of the help centre would be better, as this is a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 5):

I saw that question and although I did not make that comment I can definitely understand the frustration of whoever did. The information had to be extracted almost by force from the user.

In any case, if you find yourself frustrated simply walk away. Eventually the OP will notice this and change its attitude or s/he will not and end up with no answer and a possibly very downvoted question.

Answer (score 4):

In cases like that:

- **Flag the offender.**
- Downvote the question, especially if the OP is uncooperative.
- If it is becoming impossible to get a clear question out of the OP, vote to close if possible or flag if you cannot vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it fine `quiting answering questions`?

Sure, if you no longer want to help, it's fine.

> Either you provide us with a screenshot/photo of the "MINUS SIGN" you're talking about, or I'm done helping you.

Hmm this comment isn't great. However, the concept is 100% fine.

I'd rather see this:

> I need a screenshot of the issue to be able to help you any more. Please post it to http://imgur.com

But the user hasn't done much wrong to be honest.